# BigQuery equivalent of this query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to know the BigQuery equivalent of this query

The current script is in Oracle, I want to find the BigQuery Equivalent of this script but I am not able to proceed with the **decode** section part.
Need help on this.

query:

```sql
select e.name,d.dept
from employee e inner join department d 
on e.eid = d.eid and decode(e.unit,null,1,0,1,1,1,2,2)=decode(d.unit,null,1,0,1,1,1,2,2)
```

Comment: This looks to be Oracle code, but it isn't valid.  You can't check for `NULL` using `=`.  Sample data and desired results would help here.

Comment: That is SQL - so what do you mean by "SQL equivalent"?

Comment: That code looks like it _already is_ SQL. Are you saying you want to find the equivalent to run in a different database system? If so, you need to explain which two (you've tagged three!) Also, bear in mind that the people who can help you write the _new_ version won't necessary be the same people who understand what the _old_ version does, so a description of that would also be useful.

Comment: Which dbms will be used for the new query?

Comment: Your code already is SQL. Please specify the desired target DBMS and the desired behaviour. I have removed the three conflicting tags. Please tag only the appropriate target DBMS.

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel my target BDMS is BigQuery only

Comment: Hi @IMSoP, I want it for BigQuery.

Comment: OK, and what about the rest of my comment? What system is this query currently written for? And what does it do?

Comment: Hi @IMSoP, so it is basically a Oracle Script and I need to convert it in BigQuery.

Comment: Click [edit]. Add the **three** pieces of information I suggested **2 hours ago** (current system, required system, summary of what it does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds confusing but usually SQL Server developers call it as SQL only. So considering you need SQL Server equivalent of this, You can try below -

```
select e.name, d.dept
  from employee e 
 inner join department d on e.eid = d.eid 
                         and CASE WHEN e.unit IS NULL THEN 1
                                  WHEN e.unit = 0 THEN 1
                                  WHEN e.unit = 1 THEN 1
                                  WHEN e.unit = 2 THEN 2
                             END
                             =
                             CASE WHEN d.unit IS NULL THEN 1
                                  WHEN d.unit = 0 THEN 1
                                  WHEN d.unit = 1 THEN 1
                                  WHEN d.unit = 2 THEN 2
                             END
```